# How to sum an even series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm trying to sum up this summation series
$$\sum_{x=0}^{2m}\delta^{2x}$$

Here's what I have tried:

$$S_{2m} = \delta^0+\delta^2+ \delta^4 + \cdots + \delta^{2m} \\
  \delta S_{2m} = \delta^1+\delta^3+ \delta^5 + \cdots + \delta^{2m+1}$$

Usually I would minus the second from the first to see what cancels, but nothing cancels here. How do I sum up series like this?

Using @Don Thousands comment:
$$S_{2m} = \delta^0+\delta^2+ \delta^4 + \cdots + \delta^{2m} \\
  \delta^2 S_{2m} = \delta^2+\delta^4+ \delta^6 + \cdots + \delta^{2m+2} \\
(1-\delta^2)S_{2m} = 1- \delta^{2m+2} \\
S_{2m} = \frac{1- \delta^{2m+2}}{1-\delta^2}$$

Comment: $\delta^{2x} = (\delta^2)^x$.

Comment: First, perhaps the upper limit of the sum should be $m$ and not $2m$.  Then, note that $\delta^{2x}=(\delta^2)^x$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr It's specifically $2m$ for this case which makes me question the geometric series approach, as I'm unfamiliar on what to do when the upper limit is 2m

Comment: Have you tried computing $\delta^2S_n$?

Comment: @DonThousand Ah , thats a great point!

Comment: If your upper limit on the sum is $2m$, then you should be summing until $x=2m$ to get $\delta^{4m}$.  This doesn't seem to match your $S_n$ (and $n$ is undefined), so it would be helpful to clarify.

Comment: Do you know the what the series $\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k$ sums to, in terms of x and n? If not, try to find out and use the result to solve this question

Comment: @egglog yeah, it's the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: @MichaelBurr I've updated my post, though it seems to me you have a faster method that involves a summation trick. Could you please show me?

Comment: Your answer to @egglog is incorrect.  You gave the sum of the infinite series, not the finite sum.  With the formula for the finite sum, substitution of $\delta^2$ for $x$ gives your desired answer.

Comment: @MichaelBurr You're right, $\frac{1-x^{k}}{1-x}$! That's what I was missing, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Be careful, @egglog's sum goes up to $n$, not $k$.  Also, your sum seems to be for a slightly different sum, where the upper limit is $n-1$, not $n$.  The limits on the summation make a big difference in this problem, be very careful about the meaning of the mathematical statement.