# Handling different summation limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

My question is to understand the difference of summation limits based on these example distributions.

Let's say that $x = 0, 1, 2, ..., 2m$

Then we have $$\frac{\delta^x}{1+\delta^{2m+1}}$$
When taking the summation of this distribution I would do:
$$\sum_{x=0}^{2m} \frac{\delta^x}{1+\delta^{2m+1}}$$

However, let's change the variable and replace it with  z when $0 < z < 2m$, I get this distribution:
$$\frac{\delta^z}{1+\delta^{2m+1}}$$

But what happens to the limits of the summation? Surely, $0 < z < 2m$ is different to when $x = 0, 1, 2, ..., 2m$

The best I can get is:
$$\sum_{0<z<2m}\frac{\delta^z}{1+\delta^{2m+1}}$$

However, I wouldn't know how to compute this sum or get the right lower and upper limits.

Comment: This is essentially the same question you asked at. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326599/how-to-sum-an-even-series . Here you have two different sums, one including $0$ and $2m$, one not. Write them with ellipses ( ... + .. +..)  instead of sigma notation. Then each can be manipulated to include a standard finite geometric series sum.

Comment: They're similar but different as I'm asking what happens to the sum limits when 0 < z < 2m. I'm not quite sure that I catch you, when I expand them out I'll follow the same logic as if x = 0, 1, 2, ..., 2m but they must be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overthinking this question, and relying too much on the formal summation expression. Write the sums out using ellipses and look at the patterns.

In each of these two sums the denominator of each term is the same, so you can just divide by it when you  sum the numerators that vary.

To evaluate the first sum you need
$$
1 + \delta + \delta^2 + \cdots + \delta^{2m-1} + \delta^{2m} .
$$

You can find it using the standard formula for the sum of a geometric series.

For the second sum the numerators add this way:
$$
 \delta + \delta^2 + \cdots + \delta^{2m-1}   .
$$

To calculate that, just factor out $\delta$ and sum the resulting ordinary geometric series that starts with exponent $0$ and ends with exponent $2m-2$.

Comment: So this summation looks like $\sum_{z=1}^{2m-1}\delta^{z}$ and then factoring out a delta and re-arranging the summation limits $\delta \sum_{m = 0}^{2m-2}\delta^m$? where $m = z-1$?

Comment: Yes, But my general point is that the summation notation with its dummy index variable gets in the way of understanding rather than helping, so you should avoid it as much as possible. When you see it in something you are reading, unpack it. Don't write it yourself until you have to, perhaps for publication.

Comment: I believe there is a flaw with my summation! I managed to correctly figure it out in the end:$
\sum_{y=1}^{2k-1}\delta^{2y} \implies \delta \sum_{y=1}^{2k-1} \delta^{2y-1}$ substituting $u=y-1$ as we can do this $\delta^{y-1}\delta^y \implies \delta^{u}\delta^{u+1}$ we get $\delta \sum_{u=0}^{2k-1} \delta^{2u+1} \implies \delta^2 \sum_{u=0}^{2k-1} \delta^{2u} = \frac{\delta^2 \cdot (1-\delta^{4k-2})}{1-\delta^2}.$ Definitely a more fluid approach, although knowing both methods in deriving the answer is great also!